# Reading UTF-8 encoded XML from URL in java

Tags: java, url, utf-8

I'm trying to read XML data from Google weather webservice. The response contain some Spanish characters. Problem is that these characters are not displayed properly. I've tried to convert everything to UTF-8 but that does not seem to help. Code is given below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Noja&hl=es");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String str = in.readLine();
    //this does not work even                        
    //String str = new String(in.readLine().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(str);

    in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Output is given below (trimmed to keep the post in limits). Notice "mi�" and s�b

trimmed to keep max char limit

```
<day_of_week data="mi�"/><day_of_week data="s�b"/><low data="11"/><high data="16"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_rain.gif"/><condition data="Posibilidad de lluvia"/></forecast_conditions></weather></xml_api_reply>
```

Comment: here it is, trimmed to keep max char limit

<day_of_week data="mi�"/><day_of_week data="s�b"/><low data="11"/><high data="16"/><icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_rain.gif"/><condition data="Posibilidad de lluvia"/></forecast_conditions></weather></xml_api_reply>

Comment: I've just tried your sample and get the same error. However if I change encoding to iso-8859-1, sáb prints (my guess) correctly and not as s?b.
Firefox reports the page as UTF-8 encoded, so I would expect your code to be correct...

Comment: Changing the charset to iso-8859-1 solves the problem but it does not make sense to me. As per my understanding UTF-8 is superset of all other character sets.

Comment: @user1413028: utf-8 can encode every character that iso-8859-1 can, but in its encoded form it is not a superset. Characters with codepoints higher than 127 are encoded in utf using multiple bytes. Utf-8 can be considered a superset of ascii though.

As the browser is showing an encoding of of utf-8, maybe the server is sending different encodings to different clients, can you show the value of the `Content-Type` response header?

Comment: Content-Type text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date Thu, 24 May 2012 10:28:02 GMT
Pragma no-cache
Expires Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Content-Encoding gzip
Server igfe
Content-Length 486
X-XSS-Protection 1; mode=block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that page is xml then you should usually pass the InputStream directly to the xml parser and let it automatically detect the encoding. Otherwise you should look at the charset parameter of the [content type response header](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) to determine the correct encoding and create the appropriate InputStreamReader.

**Edit:** That server is indeed responding with different encodings to the browser and the java client, probably depending on the `Accept-Charset` request header. For firefox this header has the value

```
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n
```

This means both charset are accepted, there is no preference for either one. The server responds with a `Content-Type` header of `text/xml; charset=UTF-8`. The java client does not send this header and the server responds with `text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1`.

To use the charset supplied by the server you can use code like the following:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("charset\\s*=\\s*([^ ;]+)").matcher(contentType);
String charset = "utf-8"; // default
if (matcher.find()) {
    charset = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(con.getContentType());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    con.getInputStream(), charset));
```

**Edit 2:** Turns out the server decides the charset to use based on the user-agent header. If you add the following line, it responds with a charset of utf-8.

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

Anyway, the `Content-Type` response header contains the correct charset to use.

Comment: Actually I'm doing exactly that in my code and getting the same problem. I wrote this simple code to test things out.

Answer (score 1):

Your input may be correct, although I would use an XML parser to read the XML, rather than try and interpret this as a line-by-line feed. However your output may be incorrect.

1. What's the default char encoding of your JVM ? Check (and set) the confusingly named property  `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
2. Do the requisite fonts etc. exist on your system ? Can you check the actual character codes you're outputting and not rely on your terminal settings ? I would suspect this is perhaps the case, since the encoding/decoding appears to work and you're just missing those individual characters.

Comment: default charset of JVM is EN. I've tried to dump the output in file but still have the same problem. String thing is that if I read from a file containing same data it works fine. Its only when I read from this URL the problem occours